# Azure Data Factory GitHub Integration Private Repo

Tags: azure, github, azure-data-factory, github-enterprise

I only seem able to integrate my ADFv2 instance with ***public*** repos in my organisation, which is undesirable.

In the documentation (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/source-control.md#author-with-github-integration), it states that:

```
..can use both public and private GitHub repositories with Data Factory as long you have read and write permission to the repository..
```

So, i complete the following steps:

1. Navigate to my GitHub Org.
2. Create a new "Private" repo, initialised w/ README.MD.
3. Create a new "Internal" repo, initialised w/ README.MD. (this is GitHub Enterprise Cloud)
4. In the Azure Portal, create a new ADFv2 instance without Git integration.
5. Click "Set up code repository" in the ADFv2 instance.
6. Choose, RepoType: `GitHub` - Authenticate w. GitHub pop-up.
7. Enter org name in to the GitHub Account section.
8. Git repo name: ***No results found***

[image]

‍♂️

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how your credentials are configured, since you're using GitHub Enterprise, but... ADF does indeed work with private repo's. I have a "normal" GH account, and was able to configure ADF to use a private repo just now, with no issue. Note: I wasn't asked for an org name when I logged in - I just logged in, and was taken straight to repo selection.

Comment: i have just validated it w. my personal account, and i can concur it works fine.. ok, this is intriguing! Maybe something is 'blocked' at the org level?

Comment: Good to know re: personal acct working. Unfortunately, I'm unsure of how org-level auth works with github...

Comment: Check this and have step by step: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-data-factory-visual-tools-now-supports-github-integration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be the need to grant access as an Authorized OAuth App to the organisation. I did not have permission to do this.

You can then find it under 'Applications' once done.. but i think when you first connect up your ADF to GitHub, it prompts you if you would like to grant it.

I was not seeing this due to permissions on the Org.